# Has MvxBindingActivityView been deprecated?

Tags: binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

It doesn't appear that it's included in the latest binaries for mvvmCross.  Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in my computer, but I believe that is now called 'MvxActivity'

Comment: Correct :) Some of these v3 name changes were introduced in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/hot-tuna-mvvmcross-v3-progress.html - including the slide deck at: https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/mvvmcross-hot-tuna